# Joomla 1.5, CSS, IE7 and mod_menu

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, joomla1.5

I have a site that was done in Joomla here (I'm not very familiar with Joomla, but I have had to learn it quickly) and looks great in all browsers, except IE7.
The problem is that the top menu doesn't render in IE7, and thus all the CSS after the menu breaks. I know that it's at least partially loading because some of the styles are loading (the background, colours and type), but the main container and other divs aren't rendering.
I suspect that either IE7 is not reading the correct style sheet (there are 4 - one for nomal, one for IE7, one for IE6 and one for printing) and may be trying to implement two at the same time?
I have no more ideas for how to find the problem, so I'm hoping that either someone else has had this problem or knows how to fix it.
I have included a link to the home page of the site, but if you need more information in order to help me, just let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I skimmed through some of your CSS, and I found this section in `template.css`:

```
/* begin Logo */

div.art-logo {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 500px;
}
h1.art-logo-name {
    display: block;
 text-align: {
HorizontalAlign
}
;
}
h1.art-logo-name, h1.art-logo-name a, h1.art-logo-name a:link, h1.art-logo-name a:visited, h1.art-logo-name a:hover {
    font-size: 26px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
 color: {
NameFontColor
}
 !important;
}
h2.art-logo-text, h2.art-logo-text a, h2.art-logo-text a:link, h2.art-logo-text a:visited, h2.art-logo-text a:hover {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
 color: {
TextFontColor
}
 !important;
}
h2.art-logo-text {
    display: block;
 text-align: {
HorizontalAlign
}
;
}
/* end Logo */
```

At a guess, I'd say that the bits like this:

```
{
HorizontalAlign
}
;
```

should be this like this instead:

```
{HorizontalAlign};
```

and then Joomla will replace the placeholder. (I don't know Joomla, I'm just guessing it will)

If not, try `text-align: center` instead.

If that still doesn't fix it, you should look through all of your CSS for more instances of the same mistake.

Comment: I fixed that, but it's still not working. I'm convinced that the menu module doesn't play well with IE7, so I'm testing a different one.

Comment: Well, if you can't get it working, let me know and I'll take a look. I didn't really earn the accept on this question, after all.

Comment: @thirtydot - it's not working and I think it's because IE7 is using the print.css style sheet in conjunction with the others to render it. It sounds odd, but some of the styles are working and others aren't. I'm pretty sure it's using print.css because for that one, I made the header not show and in IE7, the header isn't showing even though it should show on screen, just not when printed.

Comment: I will take a close look at this in a couple of hours, when I'll have time to properly go through and figure out WTF is happening in IE7.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I've never had something like this happen, it's very frustrating and on top of it, I posted to the Joomla forum, but none of the 50+ viewers had anything to suggest.

Comment: Your site looks fine in IE7 now, I'm assuming you've found and fixed the problem.

Comment: It turns out that it was the order of the CSS, once I moved some things around, it started to work. The part I hate is that IE7 doesn't really seem to have any debug tools, that's why it took me so long to figure it out. Although I'm using IETester because my windows box has IE8 and that's the only way I know to test it.